# How to straighten edges on UV?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Is there a way to straighten the outline edges without manually moving each vertices one by one? I have tried marking seams in different areas, following quads but nothing has been helpful so far. I can't think of any other ways to straighten the edges other than moving one vertices at a time. What would be the best option for this?

[image: this is what is looks like]

this is what it looks like

[image: this is what I want it to look like]

this is what I want it to look like

Comment: Follow Active Quads or the UV Square addon and > To Grid by Shape? Or please share one of your object:https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you select multiple verticies, you can align them. I hope that is what you are after.

[image]

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't actually make the edges align straight like how I want :( it basically merges the edge in the middle

Comment: Whatever verticies you select will be centred when you align, but you can then move them as a group and snap to another point or grid etc. I agree is still a bit mandraulic, but I am not sure of another way.